# Can not autowire QuartzProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, quartz

I want to implement Quartz to my spring project to schedule jobs. I have a configuration class however, I can not autowire QuartzProperties.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private QuartzProperties quartzProperties;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerJobFactory jobFactory = new SchedulerJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putAll(quartzProperties.getProperties());
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(properties);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Error;

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Is [`QuartzAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration.java#L63) enabled? (This informartion is printed on startup when [debug logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-startup-failure) enabled.)

Comment: No, it wasn't but I tried that after your suggestion and it is still the same. Thanks anyway pal  @出羽和之

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who got a similar problem, I guess there is an issue with springboot quartz version 2.1.8. The problem has solved when I implement liquibase to my project.